# How do I access a has_many relationship from a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a form where I am creating a new project.

```
= form_for(@project, :html => { :class => 'addProjectForm' }) do |f|
  #actions
    = f.submit
  %p
    = f.label :name
    %br
    = f.text_field :name, :class => 'projectName'
  %p
    = f.label :ticket
    %br
    = f.text_field :ticket, :class => 'ticket'
 %p
    = f.label "Crew Member Name"
    = f.label "Crew Member Role"
    %br
    = f.text_field :crew_members.name
    = f.collection_select :crew, CrewMember.all, :role, :role
    = f.submit "Add More Crew Members", :id => 'add-crew-member'
  %p
```

Everything works fine up to the point of :crew_members.name.  I keep getting an `undefined method "name" for :crew_member:Symbol`.  All of the previous tags are updating the Project table, but I cant get the CrewMembers to update.  Here is the model.

```
class CrewMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :role
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: worked fine.  Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object `@crew_member` in the action which calls this form, I suppose that would be the new action: 
`@member = @project.build_crew_member` (If you are using rails 3) or
`@member = @project.crew_member.build` (If < rails 3)

Then in your form, use the fields_for form tag to capture crew_member fields:

 `<%= f.fields_for :crew_member do |m|%>` 
`<%= m.text_field :name%>`